# terrain / floor and openlayer map

Tags: three.js, openlayers

I would like to know how I can overlay an openlayer map on a three.js terrain (or other way round, how can I generate a terrain from an openlayer map in three.js). The closest to my question is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830824/google-maps-using-three-js-and-webgl), but it was not answering my question. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to look at OpenLayers 3, http://ol3js.org/, which is currently in beta. webGL support has been built in out of the box, see: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/tree/master/src/ol/webgl I suspect you will still have to do a bit of work yourself, but if the libary supports webGL, it should be possible to incorporate three.js meshes and the like.

Comment: This question has been cross-posted to [GIS Stack Exchange](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118899/ol3-and-three-js) and answered there so should probably be closed/deleted here.